# Unexpected results from Pyhton find() function

Tags: python, string, find

I have this string

```
string = "DLR1=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|DLR2=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|DLR=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|"
```

And I want to find the indexes of **DLR**, **DLR1** and **DLR2**.

However, when I use the Python find() function I do not get 3 different indexes as I expect.

From what I understand, the function looks for the first occurrence of my substring (DLR, DLR1, DLR2) and returns the index.

If this is true, I don't understand why DLR and DLR1 have the same starting index but DLR2 has a different one.

What I've tried

When running this code:

```
string = "DLR1=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|DLR2=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|DLR=A,B,C,D,E,F,G|"

print(string.find('DLR'))

print(string.find('DLR1'))

print(string.find('DLR2'))
```

Output:

```
0
0
19
```

I found that this outputs the expected result:

```
print(string.find('DLR='))

print(string.find('DLR1='))

print(string.find('DLR2='))
```

Output:

```
38
0
19
```

My question is why does this happen and is this expected?

Edit:

@slothrop gave a nice explanation

string[0:3] is 'DLR', and string[0:4] is 'DLR1'. So both string.find('DLR') and string.find('DLR1')` give 0. But there is no n such that string[0:n] is 'DLR2', so string.find('DLR2') can't be 0

Comment: Because the first occurrence of DLR and DLR1 are the same?

Comment: Are you expecting that `string.find('DLR')` would ignore the fact that the string begins with `DLR`?

Comment: @Sayse then why does it not return the same index for DLR2 as well?

Comment: Because string consisting of the four characters of DLR2 are not the same

Comment: You might want to try `"DLR1".find("DLR")`

Comment: @slothrop I am expecting it find a match for the search word, either DLR, DLR1 or DLR2. And seeing as DLR and DLR1 are different search words i do not understand why it should return the same index.

Comment: `string[0:3]` is `'DLR'`, and `string[0:4]` is `'DLR1'`. So both `string.find('DLR') and `string.find('DLR1')` give 0. But there is no `n` such that `string[0:n]` is `'DLR2'`, so `string.find('DLR2')` can't be 0.

Comment: @FrancescoGregotti it's not searching for **words** as such: it's searching simply for sequences of characters.

Comment: @slothrop oh i get it. And so thats why when i add an = it returns distinct indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What does str.find()

The find() method finds the **first occurrence** of the specified value and returns **-1 if the value is not found**.

[str.find() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

### In your first snippet:

- `DLR` is at the index 0 (because it's a substring of `DLR1`)
- `DLR1`is at the index 0 too
- `DLR2`is at the index 19

### In your second snippet:

- `DLR=` is at the index 38
- `DLR1=`is at the index 0
- `DLR2=`is at the index 19

Answer (score 0):

Because "DLR" is a substring of "DLR1". In this scenario DLR1 is the first occurrences, so the finding operation will return 0 for both "DLR1" and "DLR". "DLR" is present three times in this text!

You should try to find the following strings: "DLR=", "DLR1=", "DLR2=" and it should work!